# Should a service unit test cover 500 Error?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have a get function that gets elements. If uncaught exception occurs, it throws 500. Should  I also write test for uncaught exception?

Comment: That's completely up to you and your intended coverage. How should one ever give a *correct* answer to such an opinion-based question?

Comment: Can you tell from the response how the 500 was generated?  If the body contains the exception message, then maybe you can make sure it's the expected 500.  Otherwise, you don't know if the 500 was hardware related, out of memory, disk failure, bad code, or anything else, in which case, it's a non-verifiable test.  It sounds like you need to prevent the uncaught exception that you've already detected (are you parsing a `DateTime` and the format is wrong?), and maybe return a 4XX instead.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that, in the future, some colleague of yours messes up the configuration, so that unhandled exceptions no longer cause a HTTP 500 status response but rather, for example, a HTTP 302 redirect to an error page.

Do you want your unit test suite to inform you about that regression? If yes, write a test.